# changing html tags with javascript and get the value on server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this HTML tag:

`<span id="pricea" runat="server">13323223</span>` and I am changing this value with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#pricea").hover(function () {
        document.getElementById("pricea").innerHTML = "1234"
      });
 });
</script>
```

Now,when I do postback after clicking `asp:Button`, the span value returns to be the original value and I can't take the new value that was changed by the JavaScript.

I thought maybe use request.form("pricea"), but it seem to be working only for input fields, so my question is:

how can I get the value of this span (after it was change by the JavaScript) in server side?

thanks for any help

Comment: So you are only updating the span innerHTML on the client? Don't you think you need to store the change on the server or get a new set of data to show? You could use the $.ajax function to update the value without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML document is not posted back to the server, only the content in the fields in the form.

If you want to send the value back to the server, you have to put it in a form field. You can add a hidden field to the form where you can keep a copy of the content of the span:

```
<asp:Hidden name="pricea_copy" id="pricea_copy" />
```

Now when you change the `span`, you also change the hidden field:

```
document.getElementById("pricea").innerHTML = "1234";
document.getElementById("pricea_copy").value = "1234";
```

After the postback, you can access the changed value in the hidden field using `pricea_copy.Value`, and use that to set the content of the span tag for the new page.

Comment: Ok Thanks Guffa ,if it my only option I will use your advice

Comment: @baaroz: It's not the only option, but one of the simplest. Another option would for example to create a cookie in the browser to send the value along to the server.

Comment: yes but all this options isn't ideal,it a little bit clumsy .I tought there is something like "reqeust.form" ,thanks